# Saving and Restoring a tabulator table

Tags: tabulator

In my app I have way a user can build a table. Populate it with data, add and arrange columns, set options (pagination on/off etc) and so on.

I want to save the entire setup. I know there's get data, get column definitions etc, but is there an easy way to get literally everything required to recreate the table exactly as is from scratch?

e.g. let tablesetup = originalTable.save();

let newtable = new Tabulator().fromSave(tablesetup);